# What is the best book on Biography of George Boole?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I'm searching for a good book which describes the life of George Boole… His family life, career, ideas etc…

Which one could you recommend ?

Thank you

Comment: This is not a mathematics question

Comment: http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: See [George Boole](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/) with bibliography. Presumably: D. MacHale, George Boole, His Life and Work (1985) (also a [new edition](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Life_and_Work_of_George_Boole/PHfPoAEACAAJ))

Comment: This is not a history question. It seems to be a question about how to use google or amazon. Where's google.stackexchange when you need it?

Comment: Also: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Boole/

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody ! Gonna checkout history portal !